# Fetching remote data multiple times based on user choice within a page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am using next js for developing a web app. I have following page:

```
<page>
   <component_1>
     Fetch the data from remote server using `getInitialProps` (I could use `getStaticProps` or `getServerSideProps` too)
     Show the data to user and get the user input, pass on to component_2
   </component_1>
   <component_2>
      Based on the user selection, fetch remote data and show it in the page
   </component_2>
</page>
```

During user interaction, either `component_1` or `component_2` is visible.
    `getInitialProps` is allowed to be used only on page level components (URL loading) and not called in sub-components (this way, I am not able to get remote data from `component_2`). Should I have to handle this scenario by using different URLs? Or is there a better way of handling in the same page?
Thanks for the help in advance!!!

Comment: you have to store user setting in context or store manager, this also fix your data communication prob between components

Comment: storing data among the components is not an issue, based on user's chosen option in component_1, I need to make remote query and get the data, Where do I make the remote query for second component is the issue.

Comment: This is opinion-based question as there are many ways to design around the issue.
I would suggest to read this https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: @NikolaiKiselev: nextjs standardizes the remote queries: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getStaticProps`, `getInitialProps` and `getServerSideProps` are functions that fetch data for **pre-rendered** pages and components.

Your component needs to fetch data based on the user actions, so you need to fetch data only on the client side. **You can fetch data on the client side in any React component**.

Example using [SWR](https://swr.now.sh/) hook. However, you can use any preferable method to fetch data.

```
import useSWR from 'swr'

function Profile() {
    const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/user', fetch)

    if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>
    if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>
    return <div>hello {data.name}!</div>
}
```

Suggested reading: [Next.js fetching data on the client side](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#fetching-data-on-the-client-side)